# Redirect URI mismatch error from Google OAuth

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-authentication, redirect-uri-mismatch

I have a Flask web application which is hosting in Google Cloud Run which is hosted with https://mydomain.run.app.

Now I am trying to add google authentication to it. I have created the API under **credentials** in GCP. I have given https://mydomain.run.app/authorize in the redirect uri but when I tried to login from my app it throws me redirect mismatch error.
And the error shows me http://mydomain.run.app/authorize.
The mismatch is the *https* and *http*
When I tried to give http in the credentials uri it throws me

`Invalid Redirect: This app has a publishing status of "In production". URI must use https:// as the scheme.`

```
@app.route('/login/google')
def google_login():
    google = oauth.create_client('google')
    redirect_uri = url_for('authorize', _external=True,_scheme='https')
    return google.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)

@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
    google = oauth.create_client('google')  
    token = google.authorize_access_token()  
    resp = google.get('userinfo')  
    user_info = resp.json()
    user = oauth.google.userinfo() 
    session['profile'] = user_info
    session.permanent = True  
    return redirect('/select')
```

Comment: Your code is specifying the **http** scheme when it calls the Google auth endpoint.

Comment: Any reference or example for https scheme that you can suggest?

Comment: What reference are you looking for? Your code is creating the issue.

Comment: I have added my code above to my post. I couldn't figure out where I am making mistake. I am new to this. Thanks!

Comment: @SanthoshkumarSundararaj
did you find a solution for your question? I am wondering because now I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

your app is currently set to production in google developer console.

[image]

This means that all of the redirect uris you try to add to your project. Must be HTTPS and not HTTP you can also not use localhost

As you are trying to use http://mydomain.run.app/authorize you need to change it so that it is https://mydomain.run.app/authorize note that the first one was `http://` and not `https://`

The error is coming because your application itself is trying to send a redirect uri of http and not https.  You need to fix your application so that it is using https.

Comment: I tried to add _scheme='https' in the url_for while redirecting but now I am **authlib.integrations.base_client.errors.MismatchingStateError: mismatching_state: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.** error. I have changed my secret key to static string instead of random numbers. But same error.

Comment: I have the same issue now, I have my consent screen verified/approved and my app is in prod mode , I created client id(credentials) and put the authorized uri with https and javascript origin also with https, but when I try to log in it shows redirect uri in http

Comment: You cant use HTTP it has to be HTTPS in prodctuion.

Answer (score 0):

Under **Authorized redirect URIs**

You should put 1 more URI :

```
https://mydomain.run.app/
```

Then check again. I have got same issue before.

Comment: Thanks! But no luck. Still it shows the same redirect mismatch URI error with http link. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: ah, please check your app when return., it should be return with https

Comment: the app should run on https only when exposing

Comment: I tried to add _scheme='https' in the url_for while redirecting but now I am **authlib.integrations.base_client.errors.MismatchingStateError: mismatching_state: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.** error. I have changed my secret key to static string instead of random numbers. But same error.